# Finding distance of closest approach of an electron to an infinite line

Tags: electrons, potential-energy

The initial distance from the line is available with all necessary information to come up with a formula. How would I get started with this.

Comment: Related: [Finding distance from an infinite line of charge that a particle stops at with given initial velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620144/finding-distance-from-an-infinite-line-of-charge-that-a-particle-stops-at-with-g)

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions.